# ASP.Net Button1 onclick won't work on the server

Tags: asp.net, button

I have a problem with my button1 onclick event,

It works fine on my local computer, however, it shows me error when I publish to the server:

```
>     Compilation Error
>     Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following
> specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>     
>     Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.resourcecenter_default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension
> method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ASP.resourcecenter_default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
>     
>     Source Error:
>     
>     
>     Line 66:         <tr>
>     Line 67:         <td class="style1">
>     Line 68:         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click" />
>     Line 69:
>     Line 70:         </td>
```

And here is my code:

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

......

<tr>
        <td class="style1">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click" />

</td>
```

C#:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlcode = null;
            string request = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
.....}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is going on?
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you use a website or web application?

Comment: Try checking the **CausesValidation** property of the button.

Comment: CausesValidation value does not effect compilation

Comment: Hi, Amiram, I use a web application

Comment: @user1451653 how did you publish the application?

Comment: Kevin, I build my application and publish it. the method I use is File System

Comment: @user1451653 when you published it and uploaded - did you also have a bin folder with your dll in?

Comment: Kevin, Yes, I have a bin folder with my dll in

Answer (score 0):

You might try encapsulating the _Default class in a unique namespace or alter the class name in case it's conflicting with another page in your site with the same class name (_Default) in it's code behind.